# In vue3, computed computes the property performance

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

In the following example, using the computed property of vue3, should we put "computed" in the outermost layer or do "computed" on the data alone? Which performs better?

```
const arr = computed(()=>[
  {options:cpuData.map((item)=>({...item,name:'tom'}))},
  {options:disData.map((item)=>({...item,name:'jerry'}))},
  {options:memoryData.map((item)=>({...item,name:'oh'}))},
  {options:testData.map((item)=>({...item,name:'test'}))},
  {options:[{name:'test'},{name:'test2'}]},
  {options:[{name:'test'},{name:'test2'}]},
  {options:[{name:'test'},{name:'test2'}]},
  {options:[{name:'test'},{name:'test2'}]},
])

const arr = [
  {options:computed(()=>cpuData.map((item)=>({...item,name:'tom'}))),
  {options:computed(()=>disData.map((item)=>({...item,name:'tom'}))),
  {options:computed(()=>memoryData.map((item)=>({...item,name:'tom'}))),
  {options:computed(()=>testData.map((item)=>({...item,name:'tom'}))),
  {options:[{name:'test'},{name:'test2'}]},
  {options:[{name:'test'},{name:'test2'}]},
  {options:[{name:'test'},{name:'test2'}]},
  {options:[{name:'test'},{name:'test2'}]},
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second approach should be more performant.

Let's assume something has changed in the `cpuData`

1. In the first case, it will trigger the whole computed property to recompute. Which means `disData.map`, `memoryData.map` and `testData.map` will be executed again, even though nothing had changed there.
2. It the second case, only the first computed property (containing `cpuData.map`) will be recomputed, removing these unnecessary additional calculations.

Also there are some other reasons to pick the second approach, described in [Vue style guide](https://vuejs.org/style-guide/rules-strongly-recommended.html#simple-computed-properties)